# EETypeLoadException when native code debugging is enabled

Tags: c#

When trying to find a nasty interop bug in a large c# solution I had to enable the 'native code debugging' switch.
When native code debugging was on, I noticed that EETypeLoadException are thrown.

I wondered if there were some issues with my interop code. So I dug in deeper. However, I finally tracked this down and slimmed my application all the way down to the following lines:

```
    public struct StructA
    {
        public ClassA classa;
    }

    public class ClassA
    {
        public StructA structa;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassA e = null;

            Action d = () =>
            {
                e = null; 
            };
        }
    }
```

So only native code. And yet, if you run the above, for some reason an EETypeLoadException is thrown. 
For all I know this exception is part of the actual type loading mechanism (the exception is handled, and without native debugging the code works as expected), but it does got me worried. 
Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: above runs fine for me. Do you still have the interop parts referenced in the project? What line throws the EETypeLoadException?

Comment: No, the above code is all that is used. The only reference used is the system.dll. Did you enable the 'Enable native debugging' and break on any thrown c++ exceptions?

Comment: I've tried a new console project (VS2012, .NET 4.5)  with just system referenced, turned on all exceptions with the above code and I get no thrown exceptions at all when debugging it.

Comment: I tried VS2010 and VS2013 .NET 4.0 and 4.5. All give me the same exception. Do make sure to 'enable native debugging' otherwise the exception will not show up.

Comment: This is entirely normal, this native exception is raised in the jitter.  Very early, before the program start running.  Exactly why is hard to see, the Compiler::impImportBlockCode() is a *very* large method.  Microsoft does use exceptions for flow-control if it speeds up code.  Just ignore this.

Comment: Thanks Hans, that's exactly what I wanted to hear ;-)